# Sending cursor coordinates to C++ and storing them in a structure and append to main.qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am able to drag an image widget at some (x,y) positions, I am able to get these coordinates and see them on console with the functionally of `console.log()`

What I need is that sending these `(x,y)` coordinates to C++ and store them in a structure.

My task is to append (x,y)  coordinates values of image widget in
main.qml

```
ImageWidget {
    id: phone_icon
    x:353;y:96
    height:63;width:37
    onXChanged: {
        console.error(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  X = ", x)
        Update.update_dataX(X)
    }
    onYChanged: {
        console.error(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  Y = ", y)
        Update.update_dataY(Y)
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your post. And try to be more clear to explain your question. You may visit and check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) What did you try up to now? It seems you just need to send data from qml to cpp side.

Comment: i have edited my questioncould please check it

Comment: I would suggest to split the problem into multiple subproblems: obtaining the requested position, passing it to C++, ... Please ask a specific question about these subproblems if needed.

Comment: @m7913d Hi sir , how can i append stored values to qml file, Like i have stored x position value and y position value how can i update values to x and y in qml

Comment: I do not understand your question. Is it about sending data from QML to C++ or is it another question. Have you had a look at the answer of Yunus?

Comment: yes sir sending data from QML to C++ and have to store it and again that data should update in qml

Comment: Thanks alot @YunusTemurlenk  yes it is storing the cursors position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for guideline.

Implementation:

- when you moved mouse on the window, takes the x,y coordinate values of mouse cursor
- send X and Y values to C++ side
- store the values in an array inside struct
- When you clicked the test button, it shows the array elements stored.

## **main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <store.h>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterType<Store>("Store", 1, 0, "Store");
    Store store;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("Store", &store);

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

## **store.cpp**

```
#include "store.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


struct coordinates
{
    vector<int> x_points;
    vector<int> y_points;

}call_struct;

Store::Store(QObject *parent)
{

}

void Store::store_dataX(int x)
{
    call_struct.x_points.push_back(x);
}

void Store::store_dataY(int y)
{
    call_struct.y_points.push_back(y);

}

void Store::result()
{
    for(int kk:call_struct.x_points)
        cout<<kk<<endl;
}
```

## **store.h**

```
#ifndef STORE_H
#define STORE_H

#include <QObject>


class Store: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Store(QObject *parent = nullptr);

public slots:

    void store_dataX(int x);
    void store_dataY(int y);
    void result();


};

#endif // STORE_H
```

## **main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent

        hoverEnabled: true

        onMouseXChanged:
        {
            Store.store_dataX(mouseX)
        }
        
        onMouseYChanged:
        {
            Store.store_dataY(mouseY)
        }
    }

    Button{
        text: "Test"
        onClicked: Store.result()
    }
}
```